# How to install Tensorflow and Cuda on Ubuntu 16.04 offline?

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, offline

I am currently looking forward to find the way to install Tensorflow and Cuda on Ubuntu 16.04 offline, but I am not successful yet.
The server which I have to manage is in the intranet circumstances, and it is not connected with internet.

How will it be able to install Tensorflow and Cuda on Ubuntu 16.04 offline?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have the dependencies like Numpy, Bazel>= 0.5.0 and Python >= 2.7 installed on your machine.
Download and extract the following:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases
https://github.com/amutu/tensorflow_third_party/releases

Fix the build with the following:

```
mkdir tensorflow-offline
cd tensorflow-offline
git submodule update
./fix_offline_build.sh $tf $tp
```

Note that $tf and $tp are the extracted directories.

Build it with the following:

```
cd $tf && ./configure
bazel --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package --verbose_failures
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package
```