# Installing Tensorflow 1.9 offline and manually

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on an offline Ubuntu 16.04 workstation using python 2.7. I cannot install the `tensorflow` library via `pip`,the internet or any other conventional methods.

On the remote system, I will be installing `tensorflow` 1.9 manually using downloaded `.so` files and `.whl` files by extracting them into a folder and adding that to the python 2.7 PATH.

I have installed all the dependencies like `bazel` etc.. manually prior to this.

How do I proceed with this offline installation process? What flow should I choose for proper installation of `tensorflow` and its dependencies?

Thanks

Comment: I have already referred to this answer, but I want a more specific reply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874688/how-to-install-tensorflow-and-cuda-on-ubuntu-16-04-offline

Comment: Are you using x64 system? What is your pip version? Also you may wanna check whl files for offline installation https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/1.9.0/py27/CPU or System requirements https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3

Comment: Are you using GPU support(You might need `sudo` access or device access). Other wise you can download from github on other computer Then transfer the tar.gz using USB or whatever. Then use `pip install <tar file>` to install. I am not sure about `tensorflow-gpu` though

Comment: @abunickabhi , were you able to install? Was there any issues with the GPU installation?

Comment: Yes I was able to install it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tensorflow 1.9` is an outdated and deprecated version. Google has removed versions older than 1.15 from `pypi`. But you can definitely download and install the later versions with `pip` (with ease)

You do not need internet to use `pip`. What `pip` does is download the package and process it locally. If you can download yourself and transfer the package then you can ask `pip` to just process and install the package for you.

The following is for `python 2.7` and `tensorflow==2.0.0.`. ([Source Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package-location))

Download the package :
( for CPU only)

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
```

(For GPU Support)

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
```

Now copy the file to your PC (which does not have internet, via USB or whatever). Then  install the package with `pip` or any other package manager (`pip` is preferred)

```
# for CPU
pip install tensorflow-2.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
# for GPU
pip install tensorflow_gpu-2.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
```

I installed in a fresh conda environment. It worked fine with me and can run my code with this packages.

**For Older versions:**
Tensorflow has only the following versions on the PyPI repository

> 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.15.0rc0, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0rc3, 1.15.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0rc0, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.1.0rc0

You can use `pip` to download the version. (I have downloaded `1.13.1`, but change the version according to your requirement). Open a new folder and download using

```
pip download tensorflow==1.13.1
```

This will download a whole bunch of `whl` and `tar.gz` packages in the folder. Copy the entire folder to the new PC (without internet). 
Amongst them you will find `tensorflow-1.13.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

Install using `pip`

```
pip install tensorflow-1.13.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

**UPDATE:**

While installing offline with `pip` install the dependcies first. 
In the above case install packages in the following order

1. `numpy, six, enum , h5py...` etc
2. `Keras`
3. `tensorboard`
4. `tensorflow_estimator`
5. Finally `tensorflow`

I did this for the **CPU** and it works fine. If you find any issue for the GPU please update. Mostly, this should solve the problem.

Comment: @abunickabhi were you able to install? Was there any issues with GPU

Comment: Yes the installation was successful. Thanks for your input.